# Receiving "Uncaught TypeError: start.getTime is not a function" despite Fiddle working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, datejs

I have a global variable called `myDataset`:

```
var myDataset = {
    "classes":[
        [
            {
                "name":"ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lecture",
                "days":"MWF",
                "times":"02:00 pm - 03:20 pm",
                "crn":"11215"
            },
            {
                "name":"ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lab",
                "days":"W",
                "times":"09:00 am - 10:50 am",
                "crn":"11216"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "name":"ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lecture",
                "days":"MWF",
                "times":"02:00 pm - 03:20 pm",
                "crn":"11215"
            },
            {
                "name":"ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lab",
                "days":"F",
                "times":"02:00 pm - 03:50 pm",
                "crn":"11217"
            }
        ]
    ]
};
```

Immediately under this, I initialize my `fullCalendar` object:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: false,
        weekMode: 'liquid',
        handleWindowResize: true,
        weekends: false, // Hide weekends
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek', // Only show week view
        header: false, // Hide buttons/titles
        minTime: '07:00:00', // Start time for the calendar
        columnFormat: {
            week: 'dddd' // Only show day of the week names
        }
    });
```

I am using the `addEventSource` to override the default behavior:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource',
        function(start, end, callback) {
            // When requested, dynamically generate virtual
            // events for every monday and wednesday.
            var events = [];

            for (loop = start.getTime();
                 loop <= end.getTime();
                 loop = loop + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
                var test_date = new Date(loop);
                var classes = myDataset.classes;
                for(i = 0; i < classes.length; i++){

                    var obj = classes[i];
                    for(j=0; j < obj.length; j++){

                        var days = obj[j].days;
                        var daysArray = days.split('');

                        for(k =0; k < daysArray.length; k++){

                            if(daysArray[k] == 'M' && test_date.is().monday()){
                                events.push({
                                    title: obj[j].name,
                                    start: $.fullCalendar.formatDate( test_date,  'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
                                });
                            }
                            else if(daysArray[k] == 'T' && test_date.is().tuesday()){
                                events.push({
                                    title: obj[j].name,
                                    start: $.fullCalendar.formatDate( test_date,  'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
                                });
                            }
                            else if(daysArray[k] == 'W' && test_date.is().wednesday()){
                                events.push({
                                    title: obj[j].name,
                                    start: $.fullCalendar.formatDate( test_date,  'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
                                });
                            }
                            else if(daysArray[k] == 'R' && test_date.is().thursday()){
                                events.push({
                                    title: obj[j].name,
                                    start: $.fullCalendar.formatDate( test_date,  'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
                                });
                            }
                            else if(daysArray[k] == 'F' && test_date.is().friday()){
                                events.push({
                                    title: obj[j].name,
                                    start: $.fullCalendar.formatDate( test_date,  'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            // return events generated
            callback( events );
        }
    );
```

However, when I load the page, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: start.getTime is not a function
```

This error appears on the third part of my code snippet in the `addEventSource`.

On the header of my HTML page, I have the following:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
```

I also tried placing that below.

Finally, I also checked my `Sources` in Chrome Dev Tools, and the library is indeed loaded.

What's weird is.. My Fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/h9cC6/2088/

EDIT:

Output of `start`:

[image]

EDIT 2:

So it looks like the Fiddle is using the Date object, but my code is using the Moment object..

[image]

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(start);`

Comment: @Hackerman updated my question

Comment: `start` and `end` are `Moment`s, not `Date`s. See http://momentjs.com/docs/ for the documentation.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage There are no answers. You mean the question.

Comment: @Barmar - I see. The Fiddle is using the date object, but my program is using the Moment object. The reason why it doesn't know what getTime() is. How do I fix this..?

Comment: Try with: `start._d.getTime()`

Comment: Use the appropriate `Moment` methods to process the times. I gave you a link to the documentation, that should be all you need.

Comment: @Barmar I don't want to use the Moment object. I want to use the Date object.

Comment: `Moment.js` has built-in methods to add units to a time, you don't need all that multiplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your code is using a `moment` object, but you want to work with a `date` object, you need to tweak your code a little bit, from:

```
 for (loop = start.getTime();
             loop <= end.getTime();
             loop = loop + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
```

To:

```
for (loop = start._d.getTime();
             loop <= end._d.getTime();
             loop = loop + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
```

Using `toDate` method: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/

```
for (loop = start.toDate().getTime();
             loop <= end.toDate().getTime();
             loop = loop + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
```

**Updated Answer**

I just updated your fiddle to use `fullcallendar 2.4.0` and adapted your code:

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/h9cC6/2090/

Comment: Use the `toDate()` function on a moment object to access the regular JS date, I'm pretty sure the `_` variables aren't meant to be used. Either way, _1

Comment: Thank you. Got rid of the error in those two lines. I tried the same with `test_date._d.is().monday())` and I received: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'is' of undefined`

Comment: @tymeJV I used `toDate()` instead of `_d`. Seems more readable.

Comment: Do not forget that `test_date` is not a moment, but a normal date object

Comment: @Hackerman Found out why my Fiddle is not getting errors.. It's using FullCalendar 1.5.3 while my site is using 2.4.0.